# Apple cider cloudy

Tags: fermentation, bottling, cider, secondary-fermentation

I made my primary fermentation since 25 days ago SG was 1.100 ( bubbling was stopped since 2nd week), today I’m going to move the cider to secondary the Gravity is about 0.980 but the cider is still cloudy.
My question is: 
- Do I have to wait more 1 or 2 weeks? 
- And how long to keep it before bottling?

Photo attached [image]

Comment: Next time, use pectic enzyme to clear up your cider. It breaks down the pectin that causes cloudy cider. You can use gelatin too after the fact.

Comment: i just let it secondary ferment and then leave it outside, The cold helps it clear very quickly.

Comment: Mine took 3 months to clear (room temperature).  Just give it time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be finished fermenting, but it would indeed be wise to leave it alone for another couple of weeks just to be certain, and the extra time should help it to clear as well.  If after that point it is still cloudy, you can try adding unflavored gelatin to get some of the haze to settle out.  This takes a few days but I have found it to be very helpful.